# Rewriting the definition of derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Please help me understand this:

NOTE: im not looking for more intuitions and more "look at this picture" and more fluff, half of analysis seems like this kind of "fluff" anyway (lacking formulaic rigor).

From Rudin:

He defines $f'(x)$ in a standard way:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$

provided this limit exists. Right after he states:

Thus $$f(x+h) - f(x) = f'(x)h +  r(h)$$ where the remainder is small is the sense that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{r(h)}{h} = 0$.

I'm well aware of what this means, and I have a good mental image for this.

My Question:
I'm looking for a rigorous argument for the equvalence of these two statements, and I looking for it in as great detail as possible, no pictures, just step by step logic, where one step really does follow exactly and obviously from the previous one. It can be very long and complicated, but it needs to be fully detailed, if something is to hold by definition, then I'm supposed to be able to actually match that to the definition.

In particular, how exactly would one rework the limit so as to end up without a limit?? I refuse to believe that Rudin just "multiplied both sides by h" from "within" the limit, which is not legit.

SIDE NOTE: Every single page I can find (including Wikipedia) claims the latter formula from the first one, and NONE will give a logical argument! Which is very strange, isn't math supposed to be a subject where we hold proof above all else? Imagine students looking at this and thinking "well sometimes arguments by 'obviousness' seems ok, and sometimes not, what applies??"

Comment: Apply the definition with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ of the given limit defining derivative.

Comment: Three answers received (four actually, but one deleted), at least two spot on, reaction from the OP? Zero.

Comment: @Did You really have it in for me, don't you? You keep surprising me, and not in a good way.

Comment: Cheap rhetorical tricks, again? But I see you addressed the points raised... Good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\text{Define } r(h):= f(x+h) - f(x)-f'(x)h \\ f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \iff \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h) - f(x)-f'(x)h}{h} = 0 \\ \iff \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{r(h)}{h} = 0$$

Comment: Thank you. Can you see why this is, at least for me, a bit unintuitive to FIRST define $r(h)$ and THEN make the calculation? When trying myself I started with "definition of derivative" and wanted to end up with $f(x) - f(x+h) = ... = ...= ... = f'(x)h + r(h)$ which didn't seem possible. Thus the frustration. The wisdom: start elsewhere. Maybe one day "elswewhere" will come more naturally.

Answer (score 1):

Given $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable at $x$, then we can define the remainder $$r(h):= f(x+h)-f(x)-f^\prime(x)h. $$

By the definition of the derivative existing at $x$ we have that $$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{r(h)}{h} =\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)}{h}-f^\prime(x) = 0.$$

There exists a formulation of being differentiable at a point that is similar and sometimes useful. In particular, the function $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if and only if there exists a function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous at $0$ and $$f(x+h)=f(x) + hg(h). $$ In this case, $g(0)=f^\prime(x).$